# how can i send images from the client to the server (Socket python)

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter, server

**Clients**

```
import socket

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"
SERVER = "192.168.1.105"
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)

def send(msg):
    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    msg_length = len(message)
    send_length = str(msg_length).encode(FORMAT)
    send_length += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_length))
    client.send(send_length)
    client.send(message)
    print(client.recv(2048).decode(FORMAT))



send(DISCONNECT_MESSAGE)
```

**Server**

```
import socket 
import threading

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)




def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")

    connected = True
    while connected:
        msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
        if msg_length:
            msg_length = int(msg_length)
            msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
            if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                connected = False

            print(f"[{addr}] {msg}")
            conn.send("Msg received".encode(FORMAT))

    conn.close()


def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount() - 1}")


print("[STARTING] server is starting...")
start()
```

** So my idea is that I want to put the client file on my second computer and this client will take a screenshot
On each mouse click and then sends this img to the server and removes it from the second computer **
If anyone has a solution, please help me, and thank you.
notice : this for local connection

Comment: Does your sister know you are doing this? This sounds a bit unethical.

Comment: @BryanOakley No, I just want to try it, no anything else
This is my sister you know

Comment: @BryanOakley Let's say I have two computers, and I want to create this "program" for my business, so what do you think

Comment: I think it still sounds unethical.

Comment: @BryanOakley What !! I told you that i have 2 computer and both of them are mine